# Quiz questions duplicate issue

Tags: java, android, for-loop, while-loop, repeat

I'm new to Android Java programming and I'm having issues with my Quiz questions (50 questions in total) repeating themselves. My questions and answers are added to a Map. I then call my method setQuestion() to display my questions and answers, which are all working perfectly.

```
Map<String, String> userQuestions = new HashMap<String, String>();

int questionNumber = 1;

//all my questions go here

setQuestion();
}

public void setQuestion() 
{

Random randomQuestions = new Random();             
    List questions = new ArrayList<>();                          
    List repeatedQuestions = new ArrayList<>();         
    for (int i = 0; i <questionNumber; i++) 
       {
        while (true) 
          {
            questionNumber = randomQuestions.nextInt(50) +1;
            if (!questions.contains(randomQuestions)) 
              {                                                                                        
                repeatedQuestions.add(repeatedQuestions);
                break;
              }
           }
        }    
}
```

**My second attempt:**

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(userQuestions.keySet()); 
Collections.shuffle(list, new Random(questionNumber));
```

I tried to convert my HashMap into a list to hopefully be able to use Collections.shuffle. Unfortunately this does no shuffling and my questions are in no random order.

**My third attempt:**

```
Random randomQuestions = new Random();
List<Integer> questions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Integer questionNumber = randomQuestions.nextInt(50) + 1;
    if (!questions.contains(questionNumber))
    {
       questions.add(questionNumber);
    }
```

This does randomize my questions, however I'm still getting duplicates. I'm really confused to why it's not adding my previously called question number?.

Comment: maybe you have the problem in the while statement? If the problem is repeat most of the causes are the while statements.

Comment: when you do questions.contains(randomquestions) this really didnt doing what you think. you should really be using nested for loops. but im also have a hard time following your code because its not correctly syntaxed

Comment: if you have a list of, lets say 1,000 questions, and then you want to pick 50 random ones. you would do something like a for loop based on 50. use Random() to get a random numbers between 1-1000. once you have that, list.get(randomNumber) to get that question. thats the easiest way, if you need to see code, let me know.

Comment: I apologize for my syntax, if you could show me the code please, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. I have my 50 questions which i want to see and then for the quiz to end.

Comment: Please help, I've tried many different approaches and I'm unable to prevent the duplicates. Are Hash maps unable to prevent duplicate entries?.

Answer (score 0):

Storing Questions in Hashmap is not a good idea, You can try ArrayList of Suitcase(Structure) for storing small data and Database for a large data.

Now to generate Random Questions each time you can use Shuffle method.

**Example**

```
 public void shuffle_ques() {

     // arrQuestions to store to all Questions and Answers
     // arrQuestions.size() gives total number of questions in arrQuestions

    for (int i = 0; i < arrQuestions.size(); i++) 
    { 
        this.arrshuffle.add(i); // arrshuffle to store all the values of i
    }

    shuffle(arrshuffle); // shuffling arrshuffle so we get rearranged values of i in array

}
```

Now we can use the rearranged values of i as an index for loading of questions.

**LoadQues Method**

```
 public void LoadQues() {

    // int count = 0; (Global)
    // when calling LoadQues() method set count++ for next random ques.
    /* setting ques on textview by getting ques from arrQuestions
       and getting any random index number for question from arrshuffle.*/

    txtques.setText(arrQuestions.get(arrshuf.get(count)).Ques);
    btn1.setText(arrQuestions.get(arrshuf.get(count)).Opt1);
    btn2.setText(arrQuestions.get(arrshuf.get(count)).Opt2);
    btn3.setText(arrQuestions.get(arrshuf.get(count)).Opt3);
    btn4.setText(arrQuestions.get(arrshuf.get(count)).Opt4);
    ans = arrQuestions.get(arrshuf.get(count)).Ans;


}
```

This code will load Random question while in app and also when you restart the app.

Comment: Thanks very much for writing the code and explaining it. I do agree that your approach is the more efficient way to do this.

I just wondered, as I'm nearly finished with my quiz, that why my For loop fails to work?. I'm confused to why it's not adding previously asked questions to my array for checking.

Thanks again.